# Multiply the digits at odd position by 1 and at even position by 3

Tags: java

I am doing a question and it wants me to get 12 digits to multiply. If the first digit is odd, it has to multiply by 1 otherwise the digit multiply by 3.My program is working. However, the coding is quite long. May I ask if there is any other method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ass2a
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input,b;
        long checked;
        System.out.print("Please enter the 12 digit:");
        input = reader.nextLine();

        long one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twevle;
     checked =Long.parseLong(input);

      one= checked / 100000000000L;
      two = (checked % 100000000000L)/10000000000L;
      three =(checked % 10000000000L)/ 1000000000L; 

      System.out.println(one);
        System.out.println(two);
         System.out.println(three);

        if((input.length() < 12) || (input.length() > 12))
       {
            System.out.println("The entered digits is not equal to 12.");
          System.exit(0); 
        }
      else
      {
           System.out.println("Calculating...");
        }
       if (one % 2 ==0) 
      {
          one = one * 1;
        }
       else
       {
          one = one * 3;
          System.out.println("one is "+one);
        }
           if (two % 2 ==0)
      {
          two = two * 1;
        }
        else 
        {

            two = two * 3;
             System.out.println("two is "+two);
        }
         if (three % 2 ==0)
      {
          three = three * 1;
        }
        else 
        {

            three = three * 3;
             System.out.println("three is "+three);
        }
        System.out.println(one);
        System.out.println(two);
         System.out.println(three);
        long sum = one +two+three;
          System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: we want do your homework

Comment: _"My program is working. However, the coding is quite long."_ Then go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also using the C++ bracket style won't never help to have fewer lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating individual variables, you could store the values in an array with length 12 and iterate that array:

```
long[] digits = new long[12];
// Add the input to the array
...
for(int i=0;i<digits.length;i++){
  if(digits[i]%2==0){
        digits[i] *= 3;
  }
}
```

This is not complete code, but just an example to get you started. You can read up on [Java arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Thanks but the question wants me to enter the 12 digits into a variable.

Comment: Yes, you already do it in the `checked` variable. You store 12 variables (`one`...`twelve`), I suggest an array instead of these 12.

Comment: However, I don't know how to limit one array variable to store one digit. For example, user can enter 444 into one array variable, please advise.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have understood what you mean.